# How do we modify Controller API request URL in Swagger?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, swagger

I'm working on Swagger implementation for Java Spring MVC project.(NON-Spring Boot project, manually deploy on tomcat 9.0v)

```
URL for Swagger : http://localhost:8080/kes/v1.0/swagger-ui/index.html
```

so when hitting any Controller API, the request URL the Swagger forms is this

```
Actual   : http://localhost:8080/v1.0/kes/swagger-ui/index.html
Expected : http://localhost:8080/kes/v1.0/swagger-ui/index.html

actual /v1.0/kes/
expected /kes/v1.0/
```

Due to this issue I m getting 404 error.
I tried multiple options inclueding change url pattern in web.xml, but didn't resolve.

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <!--scope>compile</scope-->
        </dependency>
```

Configuration is this

```
package com.pen.lis.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-ui/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/");
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.eds.kes.controller")).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your project via github for a quicker resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change the URL pattern in your Swagger configuration to match the actual URL of your API endpoints and restart the tomcat.

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/kes/v1.0/swagger-ui/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/");
}
```

Comment: It is not working, it throws error [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (DispatcherServlet.java:1283) - No mapping for GET /kes/v1.0/swagger-ui/index.html, also tried multiple scenarios, none worked, Swagger actually does not work when changing  to addResourceHandler("/kes/v1.0/swagger-ui/**")